# Action Script 3 App for Android - Block device buttons?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, button, blocking

Hy, i am developing an app to Android with Action Script 3.

In some point of my app, i need to block the phisycal buttons of the device ( volume buttons, power button, and any other buttons who the device might have )...

It's possible to do this with Action Script 3? Anyone know how?

Tnx a lot! Cya!

Comment: absolutely not!  there certainly is not and should not be any official APIs in AIR or Java that would allow a programmer to hijack and user's device like this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot disable *all* physical buttons of the device, least using Action Script 3.